# Finding a subset of objects with max value with constraints

Tags: algorithms

There are m people and n kinds of objects. Each person has exactly one instance of each kind of objects, but these objects have different values associated. Now I want to find a subset of objects from all those m*n objects satisfying the condition: it should have p objects of each kind (p < m), and a person cannot contribute more than p objects. I want to maximize the total value of the objects picked. I have tried several obvious greedy algorithms, but none of them has found the optimal solution. Is there an algorithm that is not NP hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure. You can solve this problem using [Minimum Cost Maximum Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) technique. With this algorithm you can find the maximum flow in a network with weighted edges that have minimum total weight (weights can be negative). So let's build the model that fits our problem best.

Build the following graph

[image]

- There are $n$ nodes in the set $A$ that represent each person.
- There are $m$ nodes in the set $B$ that represent each type of object.

The set $A$ and $B$ are full connected the edge $e_{i,j}$ that connects node $A_i$ and $B_j$ has:

- capacity: 1 (It can be taken at most once)
- cost: $-w_{i,j}$ (We are looking maximum which is the same as minimize the negation of each value)

Source node $S$ is connected with an edge to each node in the set $A$.

- capacity: $p$ (each person can carry at most $p$ objects)
- cost: 0

Nodes on set $B$ are connected to target node $T$.

- capacity: $p$ (each object can be carried by at most $p$ persons)
- cost: 0

Maximum flow in this graph is $m * p$ since there is an answer where each object is taken exactly $p$ times.
Minimum cost is the negation of the answer you are looking for.

This problem is in P.